# Angular 9 SSR | unable to access ads.txt file

Tags: angular

I need to add access to `ads.txt` at https://www.dosgamesworld.com/ads.txt

But when I click on the link I get a 504 HTTP error back.

Here is where I places `ads.txt` in my project (same level as `favicon.ico` and `sitemap.xml`)

[image]

And here is how I see it in the `dist` folder

[image]

This is the configuration at `angular.json`

```
    "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/robots.txt",
      "src/sitemap.xml",
      "src/ads.txt",
      "src/assets",
      {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "node_modules/js-dos/dist",
      "output": "assets/dos/"
      },
      "src/manifest.webmanifest"
    ],
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is working properly, maybe you had caching issues.

```
google.com, pub-6972690131935125, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
```